# Insert javascript Array into database by clicking a button php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have the following code:
- the javascript helps me select a text file and it chooses only the id from the text file. example of text file is below:

```
ID,Name,Surname
re-002,ram,kelu
rf-897,rem,juke
```

When i added the button 'loader', the javascript readText no longer displays the id that it took from the text file.

What i want to do is to allow user to select a text file, read only the ids, and then place the ids in my database.

My html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>reading file</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var reader = new FileReader();
function readText(that){

    if(that.files && that.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {  
            var output=e.target.result;
            //process text to show only lines with "-":     
            output = output.split("\n").filter((line, i) => i != 0).map(line => line.split(",")[0]).join("<br/>\n");
            document.getElementById('main').innerHTML= output;
        };//end onload()
        reader.readAsText(that.files[0]);   
    }

    } 

$("#loader").on("click", function(){
    var upload = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "loader.php",
                        data: {array:output},
                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend: function() {
                        }
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Utilisateur Nomm&#233; </h1>
<h3> Import : <button id="loader" onclick='btn()'> Import</button>
<h3> Choose file : <input type="file" onchange='readText(this)' />

</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

My php page 'loader.php':

```
<?php
  define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
  define ( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
  define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
  define ( 'DB_NAME', 'dbapp' );

 $array = json_decode($_POST['output']);

 $mysqli = new mysqli('DB_HOST','DB_USER','DB_PASSWORD','DB_NAME');

$arr_id =   $mysqli->real_escape_string($array[0]);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//MySqli Insert Query
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `user` (id) VALUES($arr_id)");

if($insert_row){
print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br 
/>'; 
}else{
die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
}
// close connection 
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Probably because your new code has a compile error in it. That would mean the whole js script would not compile and therefore not run. Did you check your browsers console (F12) for error messages

Comment: Is it only the display part that is not working anymore? You display the elements you read from the file in an element with the ID "main", did you by any chance remove that element?

Comment: @taalas the display is part of the problem, when i added the function for the loader, that is when the display stopped working, if i remove the function, it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is brittle. But moving `output` declaration outside readText might help actually send some data

```js
var output; // move the output declaration here

var reader = new FileReader();

function readText(that) {

    if (that.files && that.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            output = e.target.result;
            //process text to show only lines with "-":     
            output = output.split("\n").filter((line, i) => i != 0).map(line => line.split(",")[0]).join("<br/>\n");
            document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = output;
        }; //end onload()
        reader.readAsText(that.files[0]);
    }

}

function btn() {
    var upload = new XMLHttpRequest();
    upload.open("POST", "loader.php");
    upload.send(JSON.stringify({ array: output }))
    upload.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (upload.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (upload.status === 200) {
                alert(upload.responseText);
            } else {
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<main id="main"></main>
<h1> Utilisateur Nomm&#233; </h1>
<h3> Import : <button id="loader" onclick="btn()"> Import</button>
<h3> Choose file : <input type="file" onchange='readText(this)' />
```

Bonus: done without jQuery.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: thanks, the display part is working, i am still trying the php part where i have to send data to the database

Comment: you need to change the content of output and actually send something that will be usable by PHP. if it's a CSV file, you need to parse it and transform it into a JS array in the client, or parse the file in PHP, so no json_decode, use a php CSV function,  change upload.send into upload.send(output) .

Comment: I am not being able to make it work, even when i change upload.send to upload.send(output) I am getting error 'call to member function on a non-object'

Comment: the javascript + html should work , upload is just a XMLHttpRequest object, and is defined in the btn callback, you must have another error, but the script is working without an error you can even run it right here on stackoverflow , click on the blue button 'Run Code Snippet' .